# Interpreting adfTest results in R

Tags: r, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I do have a problem interpreting the results I got when I ran `adfTest` from "fUnitRoots" package in R.

The test results are:

```
> Title: Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

> Test Results:
  PARAMETER:
    Lag Order: 1
  STATISTIC:
    Dickey-Fuller: -9.9836
  P VALUE:
    0.01 

>Description:
 Wed Jun 29 11:24:57 2016 by user: Alexander

>Warning message:
In adfTest(y, type = "nc") : p-value smaller than printed p-value
> adfTest(diff(y),type = "nc")

>Title:
 Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

>Test Results:
  PARAMETER:
    Lag Order: 1
  STATISTIC:
    Dickey-Fuller: -33.097
  P VALUE:
    0.01 

>Description:
 Wed Jun 29 11:24:57 2016 by user: Alexander

>Warning message:
In adfTest(diff(y), type = "nc") : p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

I read it the way, that in both the normal times series as well in the differenced time series the p-value is too small thus we would have non-stationarity still. However I try to get stationarity with this data set. Thus I am wondering if someone of you maybe could help me to interpret the results or tell me what to do with the data to get them stationary?

The PP test give me the following results:

```
> Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

> data:  y
Dickey-Fuller Z(alpha) = -36.289, Truncation lag parameter = 7, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

> Warning message:
In pp.test(y, lshort = TRUE) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
> pp.test(diff(y),lshort=TRUE)
> Phillips-Perron Unit Root Test

> data:  diff(y)
Dickey-Fuller Z(alpha) = -204.72, Truncation lag parameter = 7, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

> Warning message:
In pp.test(diff(y), lshort = TRUE) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

I am really confused.

Comment: For what it's worth, I once spent a whole summer working with these tests and I still need to write down the hypotheses and work it out on paper every time. It's hard to keep it all in your head

Answer (score 4):

Both tests **reject** their respective null hypotheses (hint: low $p$-value associated with the test statistic points to a rejection) in favour of the alternative.

**Alternative** hypothesis in both cases is **stationarity** (which can be seen explicitly in the case of the Phillips-Perron test).

So you have evidence against the null of unit root in favour of the alternative of stationarity. I do not see a problem.